# How can i serve from localhost?

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack-dev-server

I have a react app which is using the webpack dev server. The server proxies into another web api for CRUD. I can use it when running locally but when building the container, the app does not connect.

[image: Error]

**Webpack config**

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3001,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4567/streams',
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . ./
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: fm-admin
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    command: npm start
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    stdin_open: true
```

Further more, when i swapped the host from **localhost** to **0.0.0.0**, I am getting the following error

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request  from 0.0.0.0:3001 to http://localhost:4567/streams (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

But the streams api is running.

Hoping i can get some help here.

Comment: Did you expect port 5000 or 4567 to work with `3001:3001`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have realised that the logs was not correct. I have updated it. 

I am expecting this app to proxy into ```http://localhost:4567/streams```

Answer (score 0):

The whole context is not described very precisely in the question, especially the service listening at `'http://localhost:4567`.

I assume that `target: 'http://localhost:4567/streams'` is executed inside the container that is listening on `:3000` in the attempt to proxy to `:4567`.
If this is true, then it is normal to lack the connectivity. When `localhost` is used inside the container, the container will try to proxy into itself on `:4567`.

If you are trying to reach a service that is listening on `:4567` on the host machine, you probably need to use the IP address of the `docker0` interface, instead of `localhost` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/13736525).

Comment: The scenerio is what you have described. Thank you for the link. I will go through it and will try resolving it.

Comment: most likely, you need to replace `localhost` with `172.17.0.1`, which is the default bridge subnet address. You can simply run `ip a` and look for the address that is assigned to the docker0 network interface